# Help with custom widget

Tags: widgets

I've tried methods of creating a custom widget and have had no luck. I am looking to 'widgetize" a template and allow an end-user to only update text in the widgetized areas. It seems like this is pretty cut and dry looking at the codex, but I can't seem to get anything to output. The widget appears in the admin panel and I am able to store the text, just no output. I'm sure I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

Here's the plugin: (code updated)

```
class Header_Slide extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Register widget with WordPress.
 */
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'header_slide', // Base ID
        __('Header Slide', 'text_domain'), // Name
        array( 'description' => __( 'Use this widget to edit the first slider section', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
    );
}

/**
 * Front-end display of widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::widget()
 *
 * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
 * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    echo $args['before_widget'];

    ?>

    <div id="form_slider" data-anchor="form_slider">
        <ul class="form-bxslider list-unstyled">                
            <li>
                <div class='list-forstart fin_1'>
                    <h2 class='h-Bold'>
                        <?php           
                        if ( ! empty ($instance['headline1'])) {
                            echo $instance['headline1'];                        
                        };
                        ?>
                    </h2>
                    <p class='desc'>
                        <?php
                        if (!empty ($instance['blurb1'])) {                     
                            echo $instance['blurb1'];
                        };
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class='img-slider hidden-xs slide-man1 fin_2'></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class='list-forstart fin_1'>
                    <h2 class='h-Bold'>
                        <?php
                            if (!empty ($instance['headline2'])) {
                                echo $instance['headline2'];
                            };
                        ?>
                    </h2>
                    <p class='desc'>
                        <?php
                            if (!empty ($instance['blurb2'])) {                     
                                echo $instance['blurb2'];
                            };
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class='img-slider hidden-xs slide-man2 fin_2'></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class='list-forstart fin_1'>
                    <h2 class='h-Bold'>
                        <?php
                            if (!empty ($instance['headline3'])) {
                                    echo $instance['headline3'];
                            };
                        ?>
                    </h2>
                    <p class='desc'>
                        <?php
                            if (!empty ($instance['blurb3'])) {                     
                                echo $instance['blurb3'];
                            };
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="img-slider hidden-xs slide-man3 fin_2"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
         <div class="bx-controls bx-has-pager bx-has-controls-direction" id='dafault_pager'>
            <div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager">
                <div class="bx-pager-item">
                    <a class="bx-pager-link  active" data-slide-index="0" href="#"><span></span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="bx-pager-item">
                    <a class="bx-pager-link  " data-slide-index="1" href="#"><span></span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="bx-pager-item lastItem">
                    <a class="bx-pager-link " data-slide-index="2" href="#"><span></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix visible-xs visible-md"></div>

    </div>
<?php

echo $args['after_widget'];                 

}

/**
 * Back-end widget form.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::form()
 *
 * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
 */
public function form( $instance ) {
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'headline1' ] ) ) {
        $headline1 = $instance[ 'headline1' ];
    }
    else {
        $headline1 = __( 'New Headline1', 'text_domain' );
    }
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'blurb1' ] ) ) {
        $blurb1 = $instance[ 'blurb1' ];
    }
    else {
        $blurb1 = __( 'New Blurb1', 'text_domain' );
    }
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'headline2' ] ) ) {
        $headline2 = $instance[ 'headline2' ];
    }
    else {
        $headline2 = __( 'New Headline2', 'text_domain' );
    }
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'blurb2' ] ) ) {
        $blurb2 = $instance[ 'blurb2' ];
    }
    else {
        $blurb2 = __( 'New Blurb2', 'text_domain' );
    }
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'headline3' ] ) ) {
        $headline3 = $instance[ 'headline3' ];
    }
    else {
        $headline3 = __( 'New Headline3', 'text_domain' );
    }
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'blurb3' ] ) ) {
        $blurb3 = $instance[ 'blurb3' ];
    }
    else {
        $blurb3 = __( 'New Blurb3', 'text_domain' );
    }
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline1' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Headline1:' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline1' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'headline1' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $headline1 ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'blurb1' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Blurb1:' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'blurb1' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'blurb1' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $blurb1 ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline2' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Headline2:' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline2' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'headline2' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $headline2 ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'blurb2' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Blurb2:' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'blurb2' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'blurb2' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $blurb2 ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline3' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Headline3:' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline3' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'headline3' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $headline3 ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'blurb3' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Blurb3:' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'blurb3' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'blurb3' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $blurb3 ); ?>">
    </p>        
    <?php 
}

/**
 * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::update()
 *
 * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
 * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
 *
 * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['headline1'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['headline1'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['headline1'] ) : '';
    $instance['blurb1'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['blurb1'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['blurb1'] ) : '';
    $instance['headline2'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['headline2'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['headline2'] ) : '';
    $instance['blurb2'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['blurb2'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['blurb2'] ) : '';
    $instance['headline3'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['headline3'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['headline3'] ) : '';
    $instance['blurb3'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['blurb3'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['blurb3'] ) : '';

    return $instance;
}

} // class Header_Slide
function register_widgets() {
register_widget( 'header_slide' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_widgets' );
```

`

on the output page I have:

```
<?php the_widget( 'header_slide'); ?>
```

Comment: You have a lot of bugs in your code. Enable debug and fix all your bugs. Also, classnames should be uppercase, like `Header_Slide` Also, we are years after PHP 5.2. so you can drop `add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return  register_widget("header_slide");'));` BTW `create_function()` is really bad. Check the Widget API for the 5.3+ syntax

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking at an older example. Unfortunately, I still get nothing to output. No errors while debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks much better and all your bugs are fixed :-). (*Caveat: I did not go through your code line by line, just quickly tested it though*)

There are however two problems left that you've missed, and that all come from when you've renamed your widget

- `register_widget( 'header_slide' );` should be `register_widget( 'Header_Slide' );`
- `the_widget( 'header_slide');` should be `the_widget( 'Header_Slide');`

Please see [`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) and how it is used. Just for example, the following

```
the_widget( 'Header_Slide', 'headline1=HEADLINE1&blurb1=BLURB1');
```

will output

> HEADLINE1
>
> BLURB1

I would however not use `the_widget()` to display a widget, I would rather create a sidebar and then drop my widget in there.

You can register a sidebar conditionally for a specific page of template

Comment: Thanks again! Probably another trivial question, but how do you output what is entered into the widget's admin panel not just hard-coded values?

e.g. the_widget( 'Header_Slide',     `'headline1=$instance['headline1']&blurb1=$instance['blurb1]');`

Or is this a limitation of "the_widget" and is something that a sidebar will handle?

Comment: That is why I suggested to create a sidebar into which you can drop your widget. `the_widget()` is limited and non dynamic as you can see. Check the codex for `register_sidebar` and how it is used

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked out for you. Enjoy :-)